# Microsoft Word for Mac 2011: Change the bold font for Avenir Book

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

Basically, know nothing about fonts, so any help is appreciated, but I've been using Avenir Book, which has a nice Bold font (looked like Avenir Black or Avenir Heavy), but now when I bold, it just spaces out, and looks like garbage. Have I done something to make this happen? Is there a way to undo this? Or is there a way to change Avenir Book, so that when I bold it, it pivots to Avenir Black? Yes, I could highlight all the bolded text in my document and change it to Avenir Black, but this feels like effort (the document is over 90 pages). Any suggestions?

EDIT: This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing to bold rather than specifically switching fonts is generating a 'fake' bold & not actually changing the font. It's a common 'cheat' in typographically poor apps such as MS Word.
I'm afraid I have no clue how to fix this other than actually specifying the correct font [perhaps as a style], but it's a common failing.

[image]

Comparatively, Text Edit switches to a true Heavy

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, but I'd even be happy with what you have, mine isn't looking anything like that.

Comment: I'm wondering if you have the entire font family & if they're all activated. Check in Font Book. I actually normally use Font Explorer Pro & have thousands of fonts sourced from sources other than Apple/Microsoft, so I don't know what comes as standard. Font Book shows these as available [& activated] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz1dk.png Also, check it works in TextEdit.